# How to configure the Hive cli when using the Spark execution engine?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have set the `hive.execution.engine` to spark and also am using a spark-enabled queue.  `Spark sql` is able to access the hive tables - and so is `beeline` from a directly connected cluster machine.

But the `hive cli` seems to need additional steps.  So far the following have been done:

** Copy the `scala` libraries to the `$HIVE_HOME/libs` dir (or we get `ClassNotFoundException`)

** Run the following at the start of the `hive` script (or in `.hiverc`)

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set mapred.job.queue.name=root.spark.sbg.hos;
```

However the following error now happens  `Failed to create spark client.`:

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.1/libexec/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
hive (default)> insert into sb.test2 values (1,'ab');
Query ID = sboesch_20171030175629_dc310c9a-519e-4f84-a632-f3a44f1df8c3
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

Has anyone managed to connect to `spark` backend for `hive` ?  I am connecting via vanilla `hive` (not `Cloudera` or `Hortonworks` or `MapR`).

Answer (score 1):

you have to start Hive metastore Server separately for accessing hive tables through spark.

Try `hive --service metastore` in a new Terminal you will get a response like `Starting Hive Metastore Server`

**hive-site.xml**

```
`<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>   
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>**mysql metastore username**</value>   
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>**mysql metastore DB password**</value>   
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.querylog.location</name>
<value>/tmp/hivequerylogs/${user.name}</value>    
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
<value>file:///usr/local/hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-hbase-handler-2.1.1.jar,file:///usr/local/hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar</value>
<description>A comma separated list (with no spaces) of the jar files required for Hive-HBase integration</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
<value>false</value>   
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
<value>true</value>    
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
<value>PAM</value>    
</property>

 <property>
<name>hive.server2.custom.authentication.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hive.service.auth.PamAuthenticationProvider</value>  
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication.pam.services</name>
<value>sshd,sudo</value>    
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.stats.dbclass</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql</value>    
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.stats.jdbcdriver</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.session.history.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>  

<property>
 <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
 <value>false</value>    
</property>

 <property>
 <name>hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition</name>
 <value>false</value>    
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>hive.optimize.insert.dest.volume</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hive/${user.name}</value>
 <description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/&lt;username&gt; is created, with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.</description>
 </property>   

  <property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description/>
  </property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
<description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
<value>false</value>
<description>creates necessary schema on a startup if one doesn't exist. set this to false, after creating it once</description>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll</name>
 <value>true</value>
 </property>

<property>
<name>datanucleus.schema.validateConstraints</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

  <property>
  <name>datanucleus.schema.validateColumns</name>
  <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.schema.validateTables</name>
  <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: Hi - I started the `hive --service metastore` as you mentioned and end up with the same result. `Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'`  .  Do you have any further hints on what to look for?

Comment: Have you configured hive Metastore ? if not configure `hive metastore` with any of the `RDBMS dastabases like mysql, postgres or mssql ` after setting up the metastore edit your `hive-site.xml` files with the updated answer.

Comment: Also place your `metastore database connectivity jar lib directory in hive' eg like `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin` Link for Hive metastore setup http://sandeeppatil101.blogspot.in/2017/05/step-1-download-hive-2.html

Comment: I am upvoting this since it has good ideas. Still not working yet - but I will continue to try in the next couple of days.

Comment: also refer Hasan Rizvi comment in above setup link, its a possible error which will occur if you follow all the steps mentioned by the author of the post.